# Is it possible to clone a single tone class's object?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

Is it possible to clone a single tone  class's object?
please see the below example

```
public class Car implements Cloneable{
private static Car car=null;
private void  car()    {}
public static Car GetInstance() {
if(car==null) {
car=new Car();}
return car;}
public static void main(String arg[]) throws CloneNotSupportedException{
car=Car.GetInstance();
Car car1=(Car) car.clone();
System.out.println(car.hashCode());//printing the hash code
System.out.println(car1.hashCode());}
public Car clone(){
return car;}
}
```

Comment: You can clone an instance that represents a singleton. why not? The question is why?

Comment: "Cloning" singleton defeats its purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can, but **Don't do that.**
Really, if you have the need to demolish the very purpose of a Singleton object, that denotes the need of  a refactoring of your class and how it is accessed.

Answer (score -1):

You can clone your class this way to get the desired behavior.

```
public Car clone() {
    Car c = null;
    try {
        c = (Car) super.clone();
        return c;
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```